# How to Extract json array within an array in android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I am trying to pass some json encoded data from cakephp to android, I have a problem when passing the data

I use
    echo json_encode($todaysdata);
    exit();

in CakePhp and when I debug this code in cakephp, I get a result in the browser

```
[{"status":{"uname":"sibin","pass":"shanu","upid":14}},
    {"status": {"uname":"amal","pass":"amalu","upid":14}}
]
```

I need to extract these two `status` details seperately in Android

I tried one code in android, it gives result, but result is repeated
I want the result of two `status` seperately
If anybody know, please help me.

Comment: *I tried one code in android* post the code you tried?

Comment: use JSONArray and get their indexes can you provide your code

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidJSON/article.html This would help a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set `status` value as from current json String :

```
JSONArray jsonarr = new JSONArray("your json String");
for(int i = 0; i < jsonarr.length(); i++){

  JSONObject jsonobj = jsonarr.getJSONObject(i);
   // get status JSONObject
  JSONObject jsonobjstatus = jsonobj.getJSONObject("status");
  // get uname
  String str_uname=jsonobjstatus.getString("uname");
  // get pass
  String str_pass=jsonobjstatus.getString("pass");
  // get upid
  String str_upid=jsonobjstatus.getString("upid");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following code.

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray("yourJsonResponseInString");

for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
{
    JSONObject e = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
    JSONObject jsonObject = e.getJSONObject("status");
    Log.i("=== UserName","::"+jsonObject.getString("uname"));
    Log.i("=== Password","::"+jsonObject.getString("pass"));
    Log.i("=== UId","::"+jsonObject.getString("upid"));
}
```